# JSON-LD schema for category pages

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, breadcrumbs, technical-seo

I'm doing JSON-LD schema for an ecommerce site. While I have the product detail pages and the homepage down, I'm running into some confusion on other types of pages (I'm quite new to schema).

I need to write schema for the following types of pages:

- https://www.example.com/pages/category
- https://www.example.com/pages/brands

...and so on and so forth. These type of pages are main navigation landers that simply provide links out to the relevant categories, brands, etc. Outside of this, there is no real copy on the pages. My question is this:

Assuming I don't include the same Organization schema on these pages as I do the homepage (I read you shouldn't duplicate schema like that), is there a specific approach to this? Right now I just have a modified version of the Organization:

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "Company Brand Page",
"url": "https://www.example.com/pages/brands",
"logo": "URL of Logo", 
}
```

We're trying to provide the most effective schema without making it *too* crazy, so should we also be including the following:

1. Breadcrumbs schema
2. Item list schema to list the brands, categories, etc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The organization is neither named "Company Brand Page", nor is its URL `/pages/brands`. These property values apply to the page, not to the organization.

Schema.org provides the [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) type. For category-like pages, its sub-type [`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) is the right choice.

With the [`publisher`](https://schema.org/publisher) property, you can convey that the `CollectionPage` is published by the `Organization`.

To associate the various products/brands with the `CollectionPage`, there are two possible ways: `mainEntity` with an `ItemList` ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/115650/17633)), or `hasPart`.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much. Would it work the same for a Brand Detail page? So the links on the above page example would lead to brand landing pages - /pages/name-of-brand/. Right now I'm using the @Brand type, but I get the feeling that's not the right use of it. 

    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Brand",
    "name": "Name of Brand",
    "logo": "URL of Brand Logo",
    "description": "Use Meta Description",
    "url": "URL of Page"
    }

Comment: @BAM: For a page about a single brand, that’s fine.

Comment: @unor As I understand, `Collection` is also another favorable option (apart from `ItemList` and `hasPart`) to associate products/brands with the `CollectionPage`, right?

Comment: @EthanCollins: Yes, although I feel like `Collection` fits better for actual curated collections, not just any category.

Comment: @unor Thanks for your insight. If I have a primary category page holding only sub categories (not products), will `Collection` be a better option there?

Comment: @EthanCollins: Personally, I wouldn’t use it, but that might just be me. Simply going by its definition, this seems to be fine.

Comment: @unor Ok. So, `ItemList` is then the better option left. Thanks for sharing your experience.